# чем отличаются Local Notification и GCM?

Tags: android, android-push-notification

Какие плюсы и минусы у того и другого способа push сообщений?

Comment: Используйте FCM и никаких лишних вопросов не возникнет

Comment: я просто недавно начал изучать всю эту тему....и наткнулся на local этот...мне интересно стало....для fcm я так понял нужно постоянное соединение с интернетом, а если мне нужно сообщение отправить из приложения, которое работает без сети? Поправьте меня, если я несу чушь))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Локальные оповещения срабатывают на устройстве строго по расписанной логике внутри приложения, а оповещения, отправленные при помощи GCM (+ сервер) приходят на устройства через сеть.

Один из вариантов удаленных уведомлений может быть такой - отправление оповещения при выполнении определенного события: новое сообщение, новый лайк. В фоновом режиме устройство не будет соединяться с сервером, но сервер отправляет уведомления на все устройства, которые должны его получить при помощи GCM.

Comment: @Phobos92 Если ответ помог - пожалуйста не забудьте отметить его как лучший ;)